# vim open buffer in existing tab

Tags: linux, vim

How can you tell vim to use an existing tab page for a file if it's already open?

I thought this option is supposed to do that

```
set switchbuf=usetab
```

As a minimal example I had only the above line in my `.vimrc` and moved all plugins (no `.vim` directory) but when I do for example `vim .vimrc` and then `:tabe .vimrc` I get two tab pages with the same file. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Under normal circumstances you'd use `:bu .vimrc` to open an already existing buffer in the current tab.  Is your intent to executed `:bu <filename>` if a buffer already exists for the file but execute  `:tabe <filename>` if one does not?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do.. thought there is a single command/options to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should read `:help 'switchbuf'` more carefully:

```
This option controls the behavior when switching between buffers.
```

So… that option has no effect on non-buffer-switching commands like `:tabedit`.

Also, `:help :tabedit` says:

```
Open a new tab page with an empty window, after the current tab page.
```

So… you can't really expect that command to not open a new tab page, do you?

If you want to edit a new file in place, use `:e filename`.

If you want to edit a file in a horizontal window, use `:sp filename`.

If you want to edit a file in a vertical window, use `:vs filename`.

If you want to edit a file in a new tab page, use `:tabe filename`.

If you want to switch to another buffer, use `:b`.

If you want to switch to another buffer and benefit from the `switchbuf` option, use `:sb`.